# PHP 7 - Session file not discarded

Tags: php, session

!!!! I know this has been asked a zillion times but I tried everything, **it just does not work** so dont discard the question please

when logging from one user to the other, sessions are not discared at all and former user data are displayed

I have to CTRL+F5 the navigator to have the correct new logged user data

I tried :

problematically I replace everything in the session variable with fresh new data from the new logged user (from DB), but some fields are still remains of the previous user...this makes no sens at all

```
$_SESSION = array();
unset($_SESSION["end_user_session"]);

$session=$endUser;    // from DB !!!!
$session["sessionID"]=session_id();

$_SESSION["end_user_session"] = $session;
```

on logout , I do this and it should destroy the session values, yet they are still there:

```
    $_SESSION = array(); 
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    session_write_close();
    setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
    $_SESSION = array();
```

this has driven me nuts for more than 2 years now

we have the issue in wamp, and on our linux preprod/prod

please help, let me know if you need more infos

Comment: [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such shot down?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/1288408)

Comment: If you take a closer look, I actualy provided some code (which is a conglomerate of things I found on SO)... btw I have been programming for 30 years now, which makes me everything but a noob...do you think I have any choice to work with this joke of that PHP "language" ?

Comment: I didn't say anything, just commented that downvotes don't have to be commented. I didn't vote.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably tried this (it's in the PHP manual), but just in case:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
?>
```

Comment: I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I now stores everything in db, not using php sessions anymore
problem solved